# Specific sum of products from product of sums

Tags: summation, products, direct-sum

I have three sums:

$A_1+A_2+A_3...+A_n = A_{T}$

$B_1+B_2+B_3...+B_n = B_{T}$

$C_1+C_2+C_3...+C_n = C_{T}$

The goal is a function that is:
$A_1B_1C_1 + A_2B_2C_2 ...+ A_nB_nC_n = ABC_T$

I'd like to represent $ABC_T$ as a function of $A_T, B_T$ and $C_T$

for example something like:

$ABC_T =  A_TB_TC_T - A_TB_T -B_TC_T-A_TC_T$

Is this possible? How do I find out how to do it?

I have tried brute force but I quickly end up with too many a,b and cs on my page :(

Any help appreciated..